# How to reference ContentType in Django's fixture?

Tags: django, django-fixtures, django-guardian

I'm writing tests for Django project with [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian). Fixture for permissions look like:

```
- fields:
    content_type: 10
    object_pk: '2'
    permission: 22
    user: 1
  model: guardian.userobjectpermission
  pk: 1
```

Is it safe to reference `content_type` and `permission` by id? Or are ids going to change (i.e. when I add extra permission/model)?

What is the best method for referencing objects which are loaded automatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use [natural keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/#natural-keys) to reference the `content_type` and `permission` values.

```
- fields:
    content_type: [<app_label>, <model>],
    object_pk: '2'
    permission: [<permission_codename>, <app_label>, <model>],
    user: 1
  model: guardian.userobjectpermission
  pk: 1
```